# How to determinate the duration of linear progress bar

Tags: angular, primeng

I use primeng to determine the duration of a process until it is completed. After the information is displayed, the primeng process is undetermined. I set the `transportState` variable to false after `subscribe` and limit the `animationDuration` variable to 5 seconds but that does not solve the problem.
This is the component.ts:

```
getTransortationEvolutionByMode() {
    this.transportState = true;    this.statistiquesService.getGraphEvolutionModeTransport()
        .subscribe(resp =>{          
          let data = resp.json();
          this.transportState = false;
    });
  }
```

And this is the component.html:

```
<p-progressBar mode="indeterminate" [style]="{'height': '6px'}" animationDuration=".5s"></p-progressBar>
```

I expect the progress bar stop after displaying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not bind the progress bar to the `transportState`, so it cannot know when your code is finished. I am not sure you can just stop it, but you could stop displaying it or setting it to 100% progress, based on the value of `transportState`.

```
<p-progressBar *ngIf="transportState" mode="indeterminate" [style]="{'height': '6px'}" animationDuration=".5s"></p-progressBar>
```